# Installing ArcBruTile and ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, arcgis-10.3

i want to use Google Maps with Arcgis 10.3 , after Some Search i Found (Arcbrutile 0.2), so
i downloaded Arcbrutile 0.2 and install it, then when i continue to register it using Esriregasm.exe i couldn't find it in the [C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\bin] Folder, later i found it in the [C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin], but it was 0 byte size and it wasn't useful in the Registration. i follow this [Article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/43712) but when i reach Step 2 in (Solution or Workaround) i couldn't re-execute the ESRIRegAsm.exe registration.
i'm Using Arcgis 10.3 on Windows 7 (64bit).

Comment: Are you getting a message or any response back from the method?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't think Arcbrutile has worked for GE for a long time now....maybe there is a workaround installing old versions or something. I had been using the BAG tool, but GE has been removed from there too. There is pretty much no reason to use GE imagery outside of GE that is allowed under their licensing. You could always grab imagery by manually typing URL (play around with the parameters in the example URL....you'll figure it out), then mosiacing with overlap to loose the credits text and then georeferencing. Type:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=52.974,-122.5&zoom=15&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=satellite

From what I remember this is Google Maps imagery not Google Earth imagery, but the same use rules apply. Not allowed to use it for anything really.