# Sync ArcMap view extent to Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth, google-earth-pro

I have been scouring the internet for this solution for some time, as it was easily accomplished in 9.x and I can't seem to find a solution for 10.x.  I would like to know if there is a way to sync up ArcMap and Google Earth Pro view extents, so that if I pan to a location in Arc, it will be reflected in Google Earth.  It would even be useful if I could just click a spot in Arc and those coordinates were panned to in Google Earth.

ArcBruTile has been mentioned to me before, but this no longer allows you to import Google imagery so it is useless for me.

I have also heard of Arc2Earth, but I would prefer an open source solution.

Is there a simple VB or Python solution to get this to work?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149345/arcbrutile-and-arcgis-10-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/ChrisStayte/ArcMap-To-Google-Earth/blob/master/README.md

This Add-In might accomplish what you are trying to do. When you click the tool, you will zoom to your arcmap extent in google earth.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Bit late but glad I could help